# Redirect only old domain homepage to new domain homepage using .htaccess - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, dns

I have two wordpress sites. I want to redirect only old domain to new domain homepage.

**Example** -: https://www.abc.de/ to https://abc.berlin/

****I don't want to redirect other pages and files.**

**I tried this** -:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.abc.de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://abc.berlin/ [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Please check now

Comment: What exactly isn't working for you?

Comment: I don't know. I just paste this code and refresh my page. It did'nt worked

Comment: Is that your entire `.htaccess` file? Do these two domains resolve to the same place? Remove the `<IfModule>` wrapper (it's not required and might be masking an error).